# Is Z discrete in its profinite completion?

Tags: general-topology, profinite-groups

Consider the inclusion  $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ where $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} : = \varprojlim_n\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Is the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ from this inclusion the discrete topology? Is this true for all $G \to \hat{G}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the image of $Z$ is dense in its profinite completion which is a compact group. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Profinite_completion

You can't have an infinite discrete subset in a compact space.

Comment: I am not very familiar with topology. I'd like to use this space to ask a minor question: I think that he asked about whether the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ is the discrete topology. Now, there seems to be another "discrete" notion in topology, which the geometric picture of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ inside $\mathbb{C}$ probably illustrates what I mean when I say that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a discrete subspace of $\mathbb{C}$. I think that its like the "Hausdorff condition for subspaces". This new notion seems to be related with density. My question is does this has anything to do w discret topology?

Answer (score 3):

No, $n!\to0$ in the profinite topology.