# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ discrete in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

**My question is**: is $\mathbb{Z}$ discrete in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Here, by saying $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, I mean $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \varprojlim_{n: n \mid m} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, as the absolute Galois group of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, with the Krull topology (i.e. the profinite topology). Then $\mathbb{Z}$ has a subspace topology induced from $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. Then **is this subspace topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ a discrete topology?**

I first thought it was a purely topological problem, i.e. in a compact Hausdorff topological space $X$, there cannot be any dense discrete subspace $A$ (i.e. subspace with induced topology being discrete) with infinitely many subspace. But later I came up with a counterexample: Take $X = \{0\} \cup \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $A = \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

So I got stuck here. I hope to see that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not discrete in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

---

Something that may be not related to the question: Actually I come up with this question when understanding the topology on the Weil group $W_F$, where $F$ is a local number field like $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

I have found the same question here: [Is Z discrete in its profinite completion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668001/is-z-discrete-in-its-profinite-completion), but my counterexample above makes me doubt if there are flaws in the above linked posts.

Thank you all for commenting and answering!

Comment: The second answer in the linked post is correct: $n!$ converges to $0$ in $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ and hence also in $\Bbb Z$ with the subspace topology.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if $\mathbb{Z}$ were discrete, then $\{n!\}$ would not converge. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}$ is not discrete in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $G$ is any (abstract) group, then we have a profinite completion $G \to \widehat{G}=\varprojlim G/N$. (The limit being taken over all normal subgroups of finite index). We can take the initial toplogy on $G$ with respect to this map, since $\widehat{G}$ is profinite and hence has a profinite topology. The topology induced on $G$ by this has the following open sets: a set is open $U$ if and only for every point $x$, there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of finite index in $G$ such that $xN \subset U$. If we apply this to $\Bbb Z$ or any infinite group, then we see that the singleton $\{e\}$ is not open, because the trivial subgroup does not have finite index. Hence the induced topology on $G$ is not discrete if $G$ is infinite.

A different way to see that $\Bbb Z$ is not discrete in $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ is indicated in the comments.